# Android: How to create a xml-file programmaticly and add content to it

Tags: android, file

I want to create an XML-File programmatically, which will be a DB-Container for content.

What I've tried:

```
    int exampleNumber= 1444;
    FileOutputStream example = openFileOutput("FileName.xml", MODE_PRIVATE); 

    example.write(exampleNumber);
    example.flush();
    example.close();
```

Issue: file `FileName.xml` wasn't created.

How to create an .xml file programmatically?

When opening a said file, is it necessary to give out the full path
i.e. `app/src/main/java/com/application_act/yourFolder` or only the file name, in this case `FileName.xml`?

Comment: It will be setup as, when pressing a button, a new XML-File should be be created, which later on in the app, new information will be added to the XML-File

Comment: "file FileName.xml wasn't created" -- where did you look for it? You are writing this file into [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), which users cannot access. Developers can access it through things like Android Studio's Device File Explorer. "is it necessary to give out the full path i.e. app/src/main/java/com/application_act/yourFolder" -- `app/src/main/java/com/application_act/yourFolder` might be a directory on your computer. It is not a directory on an Android device.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your contribution, it greatly helps! 1. "file FileName.xml wasn't created" checked through search(double shift -> FileName.xml). How to acces the internal storage? How to create then a xml File programmaticly, so that i can be used as a DB container?

Answer (score 0):

To create an XML-File programmaticly you need to do the following:

```
FileOutputStream xml = openFileOutput("xmlFile.xml", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

It will be stored in the internal Storage of your device.

To access it:

1. Start your device -> double shift -> type in device -> choose device file explorer->
   app>user>0>name of your app>files>xmlFile.xml